# SSH connection via public key is blocked

Tags: ssh, networking, security, macos

ssh connection goes through ethernet, but does not go through wifi using keys, however both work using password. On the client side it looks like everything is fine - it tries to send the key, gets success response (as I understand), but passes it and continues further. Here is the debug info:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Cyrz8JVjCrEmKx338S4joy7zdQ9nv1e2dGx0njXneZw
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Cyrz8JVjCrEmKx338S4joy7zdQ9nv1e2dGx0njXneZw
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:Cyrz8JVjCrEmKx338S4joy7zdQ9nv1e2dGx0njXneZw
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

On the server I was only able to find the following line in `/var/log/secure`:

```
error: key_verify: incorrect signature
```

I am clearly missing some understanding. Did not think it is possible to block certain type of connection. This is all a corporate setup, and it feels like its easier to reach out to community than our security team to fill the gaps in networking knowledge.

- client macOS
- server rhel

Comment: It is getting a success response that 'you can proceed with trying to use the specified key', but not success in _using_ that key in the challenge.  The incorrect signature is resulting in `SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE` (type 51) in response to the authentication request (type 50).  Is there a difference in path MTU when connecting to the server via wifi vs ethernet?

Comment: Look in the user's `authorized_keys` file on the remote system. Find the line for the key that you're trying to use. See if it has any restrictions on what clients can use it. If you need help, then [edit] your question to include the authorized_keys content. You can scramble the actual keys.

Comment: @user4556274 if you can guide me on how to obtain that information, I am happy to share.

Comment: @Kenster nope, no restrictions what-so-ever